# Jquery: use autocomplete() on input elements added to page after DOM was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, live

I am using this autocomplete Plugin working with Jquery: [jQuery Autocomplete Mod](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)

You use it by simple adding $("selector").autocomplete(url [, options]);

There are 5 Input elements (id = channel followed by a number) when the page load that's why I use this code to init the autocomplete plugin on each input:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[id^="channel"]').each(function(){       
        $(this).autocomplete(
          "autocomplete/autocomplete.php",
          {
                some options that don't matter now I guess
          }
        );        
  });
});
```

But now I also want the autocomplete plugin to work on Input elements (same id syntax) that are added by calling a javascript function (by clicking on a link) after the page is loaded.

I now there is the live() function of Jquery but I just don't know how I should use it here.

I am sure there is a nice and easy way to do it but I just can#t think of the right way at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because autocomplete adds the events handlers, there isn't really any good way to get it to work with dynamically added elements.  You'd have to modify the plugin so that it would know, perhaps optionally, to apply the handlers dynamically.  That's a fair amount of work.  An easier way is to abstract the handler into a function, then apply it to the original elements and each new element after it is added, perhaps in a callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nextChannel = $('input[id^="channel"]').length + 1;
    function addAutocomplete( selector) {
        $(selector).each(function(){       
           $(this).autocomplete(
              "autocomplete/autocomplete.php",
              {
                    some options that do not matter now I guess
           });        
        });
    });
    addAutocomplete('input[id^="channel"]');

    $('.addSearch').click( function() {
         var input = $('<input id="channel' + nextChannel + '" type="text" />')
                        .appendTo('form');
         addAutocomplete( input );
         ++nextChannel;
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Heym thanks for your quick reply. I already had to change the autocomplete.js to suit my purpose which means I do know the file already. On lines 72 - 110 the event handler functions are defined. Do you think it would be enought to simply replace .keydown(function(e) { ... }) and so on with jquery live() function with a map of those handlers as it is explained in the last example on http://api.jquery.com/live/ . I haven't tried that yet but I did try your code above put it does not seem to work (Even the "dom loaded" inputs dont work anymore).

Comment: I tried to simply add live() to that part of the Code I mentioned above and of course it did not work which is kind of obvious if you think about it a little bit longer since the functions still don't know the elements, right? But why did the script not work anymore even for the "dom ready" inputs? Are you sure your code above works (without editing the autocomplete.js file)? I am going to try it again now... I want this to work now ;) Again: thanks for your help. I am not a big expert in javascript.

Comment: @Phil - I don't have the code in front of me.  It could be that it maintains some internal state with each handler that is inconsistent with `live`.  Adding them to the individual elements should be ok regardless of when you do it.  Just make sure that they're in the DOM before you add the autocomplete handler.

Comment: @peter - I am sorry but I was wrong when I said your code above does not work. It works fine if you do not edit anything. The problem is that I do not only add one input element but a whole tablerow which includes 3 input elements (2 of them are readonly). So I cannot use the whole html code that is added as the parameter you use to call addCAutocmplete. I am trying to edit you function to work with what I am doing but until now I do fail.

Comment: @Phil - it's Tim and you should be able to do something like `addAutocomplete( row.find('input:text') );` -- assuming you rename the `input` variable to `row` since that's what you're adding.

Comment: Sorry Tim I thought stackoverflow's help under the comment box was as clever as it would suggest to @the real name of the person who posted the answer. But it seams like it ever says Peter. I am sorry for that. Not to the topic: I marked your post as the answer now because I could make it work. I had to do a few changes: 1. I add the tablerow with all the stuff needed 2. I call addAutocomplete($('input[id^="channel"]:last')). Thank you so much for your help. The trick was to put autocomplete() into a function. :)