# jQuery autocomplete to apply to all fields that share a similar name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with several rows. each row has a product column with a name starting `product`. so the names are `product1`, `product2`, `product3` etc etc.

I have an autocomplete script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#product1").autocomplete({ //product is input cell to reference. autocomplete is a jquery function that is being called.
            source: "get_sku_codes",
            messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function() {}
            }       
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works great on input `product1` but does not work on `product2` as the script obviously references a different input.

How can I modify my script to be triggered when any cell starting with `product` is populated?

**UPDATE with dynamic content**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="qty"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr>'+
      ' <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/no.jpg" /></a></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="product' +  counter + '" name="product' +  counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' </tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
</script>
```

**Dipesh update**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="qty"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr>'+
      ' <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/no.jpg" /></a></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="product_' +  counter + '" name="product_' +  counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>' +
      ' </tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);

$('#product'+counter).autocomplete(
{
    source: "get_sku_codes",
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }       
});

});

jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){
 if ($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length >  2) {  //get number of rows(TR's) in table 
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 }else{
  alert ('Form must have at least one row') // alert if only one row left in table
 }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute starts with selector `[name^="value"]`

> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$('input[name^="product"]').autocomplete({
```

#### **[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

**For Dynamic loaded**

You can use `.on` for that.

```
$('input[name^="product"]').on('focus',function(){
   // code for $(this).autoComplete();
});
```

According to updated code you can add below code so newly added DOM has autocomplete code attached.

```
$('#product'+counter).autocomplete(
{
    source: "get_sku_codes",
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }       
});
```

add above code after `append` statement.

Comment: Thanks Dipesh, tried this without luck. tried changing name to id as well. the only thing I can think of that could impact this is that the input names are being created by jquery as well. so product1 is static and product2, product3 are table row appends by jquery? will this affect it?

Comment: @Smudger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778471/jquery-use-autocomplete-on-input-elements-added-to-page-after-dom-was-loaded

Comment: 100% correct Dipesh... sorry, should have put it in original question.

Comment: @Smudger then see i have updated my answer you can use click event too for `.on`

Comment: Thanks Dipesh, I have added an update to my question, is that what you are guiding me towards? Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26456/discussion-between-smudger-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 2):

try to apply a same class to all those elements

```
$(".className").autocomplete({
```

or

```
$("input[name^='product']").autocomplete({
```

Comment: if you use product1 then it will only apply to product1,product11,product111,product1111 and so on.

Comment: How to reference the input which triggered autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

What is id `#product1` on? `div`? `a` tag?

Say, if it is a `div`, loop through all the elements:

```
$('[.(container wrapper) > div]').each(function () {});
```

where `.(container wrapper)` is the class name of the div or p or whatever that encloses you `'products'` ..naturally, you would remove the `[]` ..only for demontration and for the whole thing to make sense.

Comment: Hey Afroman, the product1 is a standard input tag inside a table cell. the table row is appended by jquery? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try multi selector

```
$("input[id^='product']").autocomplete({  //if you have ID
    .....

$("input[name^='product']").autocomplete({  //if you have name
    .....
```

**updated**

creata a function

```
 function callAutocomplete(obj)
 {
      $('#'+obj).autocomplete{
                //your autocompletecode 
              }; 
 }
```

call this function after this line

```
.....
jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
callAutocomplete("product" +  counter);
```

and here

```
$(function(){
      callAutocomplete("product1"); //remove other code that u mentioned above 
});
```

and that should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks bipen, helping me out AGAIN - appreciate it.as per above comment to @Dipesh, I tried this out without luck. also changed product1 to just product without success. the inputs are dynamically generated by jquery so not sure if this affect it. Thanks again.

Comment: yes it does effects.. since the dynamic created input is not present in the DOM when the autocomplete is called.... tyr my update

Comment: Hi Bipen. sorry, you lost me a little. are you passing the name of the object to the autocomplete function? the function then process the input name under the obj parameter?

Comment: i am passing the an ID of the created input..... if name then u can use name selector in callAutocomplete...hang on i will update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26455/discussion-between-smudger-and-bipen)

Comment: Thanks bipen. my page is now not loading. tried editing the bracket formation etc but without luck. thanks again. appreciate the time.

Comment: ok i made this as simple as possible.. without using the  `on focus` event .. try this out.. let me know